# VBA Update statement not liking column name

Tags: sql, excel, vba

This is minor issue that could be rectified change the column name, but I'm wondering why I am getting a syntax error for my update statement in VBA when I try to update the column "size" in my sql database. The statement works fine if I change the column name to anything else like "sizes" or "sizing", but it gives me a syntax error if I change the column name back to "size". Why is that?

Comment: Size is in the list of [reserved keywords](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you provide the statement?

Also, wrap your column names in square brackets. I think in general is a good practice.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TableName]
SET[ColumnName] = Value
```

[image]

Comment: Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0

        cn.Execute "UPDATE Inventory SET Name='" & Replace(Range("B" & r).Value, "'", "''") & "'," & _

                                    "Size='" & Range("H" & r).Value & "', " & _
                                    "Pattern='" & Range("E" & r).Value & "'" & _
                    "WHERE LocalSKU='" & Range("A" & r).Value & "'"
        r = r + 1
    Loop

Comment: i have updated my answer. Did you try to add square brackets and it didnt work?

Comment: It works! First time didn't think it worked cuz I only added brackets to size, but when I added brackets to all the names like you showed it worked. Thanks!